# Firestore complaince Hipaa

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, hipaa

I have a Health Care Application that deals with PHI and I am storing data on FireCloud. As Health Care Application needs to be HIPAA Compliant, and to be HIPAA Compliant there are certain steps to follow which mostly includes Encryption. Later i found out that Fire Cloud is not HIPAA Compliant. So what Encryption should I use for HIPAA Compliant & how to make Fire Cloud verify my application as HIPAA Compliant?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Firestore is HIPAA-compliant. If you work with it, you will likely need to sign a Business Associate Agreement.